# Webpack-dev-server proxy server is not connecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my webpack dev server I have set up a proxy so calls to routes beginning with 'api/' can hit the back-end server instead of the webpack server. Here is my config for this:

```
devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    contentBase: 'dist',
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
```

In my express server, I am logging a simple message whenever a sample api route is hit.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('api/hello', function (req, res) {
  console.log('hitting API request');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

However, it seems as though the '/api' requests are not reaching the express server, as no message is being logged to the console when 'localhost:8000/api/hello' is reached. Here is the remainder of my webpack.config.js file if it is of any help:

```
const Path = require('path');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

// plugins
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

const CommonsChunkPluginConfig = new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './client/index.js',
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
  },
  output: {
      path: Path.resolve('dist'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader:'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader:'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    CommonsChunkPluginConfig
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    contentBase: 'dist',
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find an answer on this?